# Convert timestamp format in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table as below

```
+----+----------------------------------+
| id |            Created_at            |
+----+----------------------------------+
|  1 | Monday 8 April 2019 8:30 AM      |
|  2 | Tuesday 9 April 2019 5:30 PM     |
|  3 | Wednesday 9 April 2019 8:30 PM   |
|  4 |  Thursday 10 April 2019 11:30 AM |
|  5 | Friday 11 April 2019 10:45 AM    |
+----+----------------------------------+
```

How do I get below table

```
+----+------------+
| id | Created_at |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 2019-04-08 |
|  2 | 2019-04-09 |
|  3 | 2019-04-09 |
|  4 | 2019-04-10 |
|  5 | 2019-04-11 |
+----+------------+
```

Basically I want to convert my `Created_at` column to `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Comment: What data type is `created-at`?

Comment: It is in `varchar`

Comment: @sql_learner are you sure that every entry is in the right format of "Thursday 10 April 2019 11:30 AM" or is it possible to have also other random strings ?

Comment: If it’s always datetimes do use the correct data type and then possibilities for errors disappear and you can use all the date formatting tools available

Comment: @ChristosK. By random strings what do you mean ?

Answer (score 2):

From your sample data you can try to use `::DATE`

**Query #1**

```
SELECT Created_at::DATE
FROM T;

| created_at               |
| ------------------------ |
| 2019-04-08T00:00:00.000Z |
| 2019-04-09T00:00:00.000Z |
| 2019-04-09T00:00:00.000Z |
| 2019-04-10T00:00:00.000Z |
| 2019-04-11T00:00:00.000Z |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oWYLTcQdsHNjeqJ4ny6RQh/1)

Comment: Appreciate the help, Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL's date/time conversion is pretty flexible and should be able to deal with your format:

```sql
WITH
    data(Created_at) AS (VALUES
        ('Monday 8 April 2019 8:30 AM'),
        ('Tuesday 9 April 2019 5:30 PM'),
        ('Wednesday 9 April 2019 8:30 PM'),
        (' Thursday 10 April 2019 11:30 AM'),
        ('Friday 11 April 2019 10:45 AM ')
    )
SELECT trim(both from Created_at)::date AS Created_at
FROM data;
```

...results into:

```
 created_at 
------------
 2019-04-08
 2019-04-09
 2019-04-09
 2019-04-10
 2019-04-11
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, Thanks !